# Features lost when exporting to a feature class

Tags: arcgis-desktop, shapefile, export

Wondering if anyone has a solution to my issue... I have a fairly large (651,714) .csv file that I imported to a map using the Display XY feature. However, when trying to exporting the data (within ArcMap Desktop) from the Event to a shapefile feature class resulting export does not contain all my records. It drops anywhere from ~50,000 to 20,000 records. It will vary between attempts. Restarting the program, or trying in a new, blank map has not solved my issues. I am sure it has something to do with the way I am importing/exporting my CSV/shapefile, but I am at loss of why this is happening. I have tried to find a similar question on the forum and have not been able to find an appropriate question/response.

Comment: Shapefile is an old and crufty format that does not handle large data sizes well. You should simply use file geodatabase instead.

Comment: It's also worth trying to convert your raw (NOT XY-event) CSV data to a table in ArcGIS first.  Then create the XY-event layer from your ArcGIS table (NOT from the CSV itself).  Sometimes ArcGIS does not handle CSV or Excel very well and there are a number of odd/buggy behaviours that are inexpllicable.

Comment: Geodatabase fixed it. I knew there was a basic step I was forgetting. Thank you all so much.